# How do I query from Google App Engine in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

I need to query a kind K in my project P in python where the kinds can be seen on https://ah-builtin-python-bundle-dot-P.appspot.com/

```
from google.cloud import datastore

client = datastore.client.Client(project='P')
query = client.query(kind='K')
print list(query.fetch(1))
```

running this does not return anything, it just gets stuck on the last line

Comment: Are you sure the first parameter for `fetch` is `limit`? I have the exact same code and it works properly... (except I'm using Flask so I'm not printing but returning a response)

Answer (score 1):

You should be creating your client with

```
client = datastore.Client(project = "myProjectName")
```

And not

```
client = datastore.client.Client(project = "myProjectName")
```

Comment: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.
I am running on windows 10

Comment: That's really weird, the exact line I'm using is `c = datastore.Client("project")` and it's working right now.

Comment: my apologies, I didn't capitalise C in Client, but it didn't change anything